# External JS on Angular 7 project and Spring

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring, undefined

Hi im using Angular 7 and Spring framework, and i need to run a external **JS** function in TS file.
I tested on a **single Angular application** and it works well, when i compile the Angular code and put the result on **spring resources** and generate **war** file the script is not recognized, the console in browser shows ***"function undefined"***.
I modified Angular.json file setting the path of the script in "scripts" section, even if i set in **index.html**  **< script src="path/to/script2run.js">**  it doesn´t works.

How can i load in spring application my JS file?
Can you help me please?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Where do you keep your JS file?

If it's working when you run with `ng serve` it should work when it's compiled as well.

So I think issue in the path. Try to see if this file is coming together with your *intex.html*.

You can do in Chrome browser:
`right click -> inspect -> Network` and refresh the page and you will see all files coming from server side to browser. If your JS file is not there than it's path issue make sure your js file is exist from where you are trying to get it.

Comment: my script is in "src/assets/scripts", also i set the path on angular.json file in "scripts" section. i realized it is problen on all static files, nothing in assets folder is recognized on spring application but on ng serve yes.
The script is not loaded in index.html

Comment: Your spring framework is fully REST? or you combining with front-end view?
In our case we have same thing Spring and Angular. We do combine JSP + Angular and Spring  and all external js script coming from jsp page which also will load angular compiled files.

Another option 
`<script src="http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/js/myScript.js"></script>`

To have this directly in your html template but yea url is hardcoded for specific environment